# Deletar Usuário completo

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia, estou tentando excluir os itens de uma lista porém sem exito. 
**Listagem.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/_css/menu.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$conecta = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
// Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
mysqli_select_db($conecta, 'car0000001') or trigger_error(mysqli_error());
mysqli_set_charset($conecta, 'utf8');

echo '<tbody>';

$sql = mysqli_query($conecta,'SELECT * FROM usuario');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<th>Código</th>';
    echo '<th>Nome</th>';
    echo '<th>Endereço</th>';
    echo '<th>E-mail</th>';
    echo '<th>Telefone</th>';
    echo '<th>Celular</th>';
    echo '<th>Cadastro</th>';
    echo '<th>Editar</th>';
    echo '<th>Excluir</th>';


    echo '</thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['id_usr'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['nome_usuario_usr'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['endereco_usuario_usr'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['email_usuario_usr'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['fone_usuario_usr'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['cel_usuario_usr'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="cadastro-completo.php"><img src="assets/imgs/edit.png" width="20px"></a></td>';
    echo '<td><img src="assets/imgs/edit.png" width="20px"></td>';
    echo '<td><button type="submit" action="deleta-cadastro.php" value="">Deleta</button>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**deleta-cadastro.php**

```
<?php
conecta = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
// Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
mysqli_select_db($conecta, 'car0000001') or trigger_error(mysqli_error());
mysqli_set_charset($conecta, 'utf8');



$id = $_GET['deleta'];
$deleta = mysqli_query($conecta,'DELETE FROM `usuario` WHERE `id_usr` =$usuario';
if($deleta == ''){
    echo "<script>alert('Houve um erro ao deletar!');
</script>";
}else{
    echo "<script>alert('Registro excluido com sucesso!');
</script>"; 
    ?>
```

Comment: *"sem exito"*, o que isso quer dizer? dá erro? o que acontece? isso é muito vago

Comment: significa que não consigo fazer funcionar. Não dá erro algum, e não exclui nada no BD.

Comment: A construção da tabela tb está errada. Vc está abrindo um `tbody` antes da tabela.

Comment: Infelizmente, não ta dando certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O botão submit precisa de um `form` com um `action`. Você está usando um botão submit sem `form` e o action direto no botão, o que não vai funcionar. E falta enviar via GET o valor de `deleta` que será recebido no `$_GET['deleta']`. Com isso, o valor em `$id = $_GET['deleta'];` será vazio porque nada está sendo enviado, e consequentemente o DELETE no mySQL não vai fazer nada.

Troque o comportamento do botão enviando o valor do `id` via GET fazendo um redirecionamento via JavaScript com `onclick`:

```
echo '<td><button onclick="location.href=\'deleta-cadastro.php?deleta='. $row['id_usr'] .'\'">Deleta</button>';
```

Agora, me parece que está usando a variável errada na query. Em vez de `$usuario` deveria ser `$id` e coloque a query entre aspas duplas para inserir a variável direto sem precisar concatenar:

```
$deleta = mysqli_query($conecta, "DELETE FROM `usuario` WHERE `id_usr` = $id";
```

Comment: Sam, agora ela consegue pegar o id pelo get. Porém não ocorre a exclusão no BD. ele ta entrando no meu laço "Houve um erro ao deletar"

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Sam!!!!!!!!!!! Deu tudo certo

Answer (score 3):

Você está aguardando o id do usuário vir do `$_GET['deleta']` porém no seu button, não está passando o id do usuario em nenhum lugar.

```
echo '<td><button type="submit" action="deleta-cadastro.php" value="">Deleta</button>';
```

Tente ajustar essa linha para:

```
echo "<td><button type='submit' action='deleta-cadastro.php?deleta={$row['id_usr']}' value="">Deleta</button>";
```

Para fazer com que o id chegue até o script.

Outro ponto:

```
$id = $_GET['deleta'];
$deleta = mysqli_query($conecta,'DELETE FROM `usuario` WHERE `id_usr` =$usuario';
```

Você espera o id a ser removido através de `$id = $_GET['deleta'];` porém na query você filtra a coluna `id_usr` pelo valor da variavel `$usuario`.

Ajuste para

```
$id = $_GET['deleta'];
$deleta = mysqli_query($conecta,"DELETE FROM `usuario` WHERE `id_usr` =$id";
```

E mais uma observação:

Cuidado com aspas simples e aspas duplas. O PHP interpreta as duas variáveis de forma diferente. Veja:

```
$id = 15;
```

Se você imprimir essa variável com:

```
echo 'O id do usuário é $id';
\\ O id do usuário é $id'
```

O PHP irá usar literalmente o $id ao invés do seu valor. Quando usamos aspas duplas, o comportamento muda. O PHP processa a string em busca de variáveis e as substitui pelo seu respectivo valor:

```
echo "O id do usuário é $id";
\\ O id do usuário é 15
```

Veja esta resposta para mais informações sobre as diferenças entre aspas e aspas duplas

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/4040136
- Mais sobre $_POST https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php
- Mais sobre $_GET https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php
- Tutorial explicando melhor sobre o uso do GET e POST http://www.devfuria.com.br/php/enviando-dados-via-get-post/

Comment: Obrigado! Vocês são feras rsrsrsrs